# Docker: SourceMap for KotlinJS not found

Tags: node.js, docker, kotlin, webpack, kotlin-js

I am trying to get my KotlinJS running in a Docker container. Normally this should not be a problem. The programm itself is a KVision-website and runs without errors. When putting it into a Docker container however I get the following lines of error:

```
:browserDevelopmentRun > 100%✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 5648f22f33affcbeb012
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 5665ms
Built at: 01/29/2021 6:09:03 PM

Asset Size Chunks Chunk Names
main.bundle.js 4.67 KiB main main
Entrypoint main = main.bundle.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4000 ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js 40 bytes {main}
[1] multi ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js 28 bytes

ERROR in multi ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kotlin-source-map-loader' in '/usr/src/app/build/js/packages/dashboard-ae'
@ multi ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js main[0]

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4000 ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kotlin-source-map-loader' in '/usr/src/app/build/js/packages/dashboard-ae'
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4000 ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js main[0]

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4000 ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kotlin-source-map-loader' in '/usr/src/app/build/js/packages/dashboard-ae'
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4000 ./kotlin/dashboard-ae.js main[1]

(node:157) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/src/app/build/js/node_modules/kvision-kvision-bootstrap'
```

I already searched for it and found this [solution](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-js-react-unstable-building/15582/3), it does not work for me. Probably because I am at Kotlin Version 1.3.72.

Any suggestions how to fix this?